# Comprehensive documentation of functionality of TextBoxFor family of extension methods?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, extension-methods

I would like to work on a replacement for the various strongly-typed Asp.Net Html-extension methods such as `TextBoxFor()`

As soon as I started off, I realized that I need to account for the behavior of these methods with respect to model validation. I though "OK, I'll grab the list of class-names applied in various validation contexts from the documentation", but when I look up `TextBoxFor` on MSDN, there is absolutely no mention of this functionality.

I could just figure it out in the case of model-validation, though I'm not 100% confident that I know all the cases these methods are designed to handle. And it occurs to me that there might be other functionality provided by these extensions that I am not aware of. Googling has resulting in many "how-tos" for the *basics* of using these methods, but nothing even close to comprehensive.

**Question**: What is, or where can I find a comprehensive listing of the functionality of these methods? I'm not just looking for method signatures and return-types here. I need a full documentation of functionality that I could use to write a test suite against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as documentation is concerned, MSDN is the best resource you could hope to get. It might not be enough for you, but that's the reality you need to face.

Personally I use the ASP.NET MVC source code (which is [`available for download`](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/)) and look through it to better understand how those helpers are implemented and how they work.

But since you have mentioned something about model validation in your question, you'd better look at the `ValidationMessageFor` and `ValidationSummary` helpers instead of the `TextBoxFor` helper. The only place where some validation is done in the TextBoxFor helper is to check whether there are validation errors for the corresponding model property in order to add the validation error CSS class to the input field.

Comment: Thanks -- of course I am aware of the CSS classes applied to `TextBoxFor`, (as well as the `ValidationMessageFor` and `ValidationSummary` methods, which I do not intend to re-work), it is this functionality that prompted my question. As I mentioned, I could just grep the class-names myself, but I want to be sure there isn't other functionality I'm not taking account of -- the fact that the CSS classes applied are nowhere in the documentation leaves me wondering, "what else?"

Comment: The source code is your friend if you want reliability. Forget about documentation. Once you get at the point where you need to extend the framework, don't look for documentation. First understand how the framework works and then extend it. But to understand how the framework works the only way IMHO is by looking at the source code.

Comment: Well, ok then. I didn't like this answer at first, but browsing the MVC source code has, indeed, proved a most enlightening experience.